# How can I save the change of colour in a button in Swift?

Tags: swift, button, colors, persistence

I'm starting with Swift and Xcode and I'm trying to make a simple app where I have a bunch of buttons with names inside. When I tap on one button, its background colour (white) and the colour of the name (blue) change to their opposite colours, so the background turns blue and the name turns white.

Is there a way to store that change so when I go back on the app or close it, those changes persist?
I've seen the use of UserDefaults for small changes like this one but they don't use Colours in any example.

Things that might be useful about my code:

- My colours are custom colours so they are stored on a different file called CustomColor which is a struct and look like this: `static let softBlue = Color("softBlue")`
- My names are stored in an array of arrays and it looks like this:

```swift
let names = [
        ["Liam", "Noah", "Oliver", "James"],
        ["Elijah", "William", "Lucas", "Mateo"],
        ["....]
]
```

- The rest of my code is the following:

```swift
let names = ....

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                
        self.stackVertical.arrangedSubviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
        
        nomes.forEach {
            let stackHorizontal = addHorizontalStack()
            
            $0.forEach { name in
                let button = createButton(title: name, target: self, action: #selector(nameButtonTapped))
                stackHorizontal.addArrangedSubview(button)
            }
            self.stackVertical.addArrangedSubview(stackHorizontal)
        }

    }
 
    @objc func nameButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.backgroundColor == UIColor(.white) {
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor(CustomColors.softBlue)
            sender.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        } else {
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor(.white)
            sender.setTitleColor(UIColor(CustomColors.softBlue), for: .normal)
        }
        
    }
```

I thought about creating a boolean variable to check if the button is pressed and then doing a dictionary with the position of the name and that variable to be stored and when I come back to the screen, recover them and "paint" the buttons, which in my mind looks reasonable but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Is this a multiple-selection or single-selection list?

Comment: Store the name of the color in UserDefaults and then create the `Color` object from that string. Or if you are only swapping between white and softBlue then store a boolean.

Comment: @son it's a multiple-selection list

Answer (score 0):

You need to do few steps to achieve this with `UserDefault`. According to your comment, this is multiple-selection, so you must save all button states. You can do it by setting `tag` for theses button then mapping with `names` array. However, I would like to make a sub button

```swift
class Person: Codable {
    private(set) var name: String
    private(set) var isSelected: Bool = false
    
    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    
    func set(isSelected: Bool) {
        self.isSelected = isSelected
    }
}

class PersonButton: UIButton {
    private(set) var data: Person!
    
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            data.set(isSelected: isSelected)
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    func set(data: Person) {
        self.data = data
    }
}
```

Then in your ViewController, make a constructor for these buttons and a function to toggle it's state

```swift
...
private func createButton(with person: Person) -> UIButton {
    let button = PersonButton()
    button.set(data: person)
    button.setTitle(person.name, for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .selected)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = person.isSelected ? .red : .blue
    button.isSelected = person.isSelected
    return button
}

@objc private func buttonTapped(_ sender: PersonButton) {
    sender.isSelected.toggle()
    sender.backgroundColor = sender.isSelected ? .red : .blue
}
```

Also `save` function to save button states & `read` function to load data from UserDefault. And a function to guarantee `names` should not be empty.

```swift
private func save() {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    do {
        let jsonData = try encoder.encode(names.self)
        let json = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(json, forKey: "Cache")
    } catch {
        //TODO: throw error if needed
    }
}
    
private func read() {
    guard
        let json = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Cache"), !json.isEmpty,
        let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8)
    else {
        initDataIfNeeded()
        return
    }
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let group = try decoder.decode([[Person]].self, from: jsonData)
        self.group = group
    } catch {
        initDataIfNeeded()
        //TODO: throw error if needed
    }
}

private func initDataIfNeeded() {
    names = [
        [.init("Liam"), .init("Noah"), .init("Oliver"), .init("James")],
        [.init("Elijah"), .init("William"), .init("Lucas"), .init("Mateo")]
    ]
}
```

Then replace hard code `names` with `read` function in `viewDidLoad`

```swift
var names: [[Person]] = []
var deboucer = Deboucer() //Declaration below

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    read()
    ...
}
```

Final step, make a `Debouncer` class to avoid calling `save` too many times.
Reference:

> https://gist.github.com/simme/b78d10f0b29325743a18c905c5512788

```swift
class Debouncer {
    
    private var currentWorkItem: DispatchWorkItem?
    
    func debounce(delay: DispatchTimeInterval, queue: DispatchQueue = .main, action: @escaping (() -> Void)) -> () -> Void {
        return { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.currentWorkItem?.cancel()
            self.currentWorkItem = DispatchWorkItem { action() }
            queue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay, execute: self.currentWorkItem!)
        }
    }
}
```

Edit `buttonTapped` function and execute.

```swift
@objc private func toggle(_ sender: PersonButton) {
    sender.isSelected.toggle()
    sender.backgroundColor = sender.isSelected ? .red : .blue
    
    let fn = deboucer.debounce(delay: .milliseconds(500)) {
        self.save()
    }
    fn()
}
```